# Bash functions work if being called separately, and failed if they are called in sequence by another function, on Mac OS X

Tags: bash, macos

I'm working on these on a mac with os 10.12.6;

I am writing a simple script to do these things for a bunch of targets :

> 1. mount a network drive
> 2. do rsync
> 3. umount the network drive

I wrote a bash script, contain 3 separate functions, each worked by itself individually.

and here are the codes :

**1. mount a network drive**

```
function doMount
{
        # test to see if the network drive has not been mounted
        target="$1"
        path="/Volumes/$1"
        if [ ! -d "$path" ]
        then
                open 'smb://user@server/'"$target"
        else
                echo "$path"' already exists.'
        fi
}
```

**2. do rsync**

```
function doSync
{
        path_source='/Volumes'
        path_target='/Volumes/ext_harddisk_01'

        echo 'do rsync now ....'

        folder="$1"

                source="$path_source"/"$folder"/
                target="$path_target"/"$folder"/

                echo "source : $source"
                echo "target : $target"
                        rsync -av --progress --delete-after "$source" "$target"
}
```

**3. umount the network drive**

```
function doUmount
{
        path_source='/Volumes'
        diskutil umount "$path_source"/"$1"
}
```

Then I wrote a "mother function" which call all of them :

```
function mainAction
{
        doMount "$1"
        doSync "$1"
        doUmount "$1"
}
```

The strange thing is, if I start with no network drive mounted, then do all these by the script that calls the "mother function", the network drive will be mounted correctly, but the rsync function would be failed with this message :

```
building file list ... 
rsync: opendir "/Volumes/audio/." failed: Permission denied (13)
1 file to consider
./
IO error encountered -- skipping file deletion
```

at this point, since script quit by error, and have the network drive mounted.

and if I re-run the script again now, with the network drive mounted, the script will skip step 1, and the rsync will work just fine.

would anyone please show me what have I missed?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: sorry, just amended my post with related codes included.

Comment: Try adding a `sleep 3` between mounting and syncing...

Comment: @MarkSetchell, thanks for your hint.  indeed i've tried "1", "2", they don't help, but make it "3" as you advised make the deal. Thanks ~

Answer (score 0):

thanks for everyone who down-voted this question, and thanks @markSetchell for the solution - simply add `sleep 3` among the 3 functions made it.